# Python: Recursively convert int to binary string

Tags: python

I am trying to recursively convert int to binary string but I don't really understand how the whole positive int to binary string conversion works.

Also found out that apparently each position is like a representation of the power of 2.

Any explanation as to how to convert a positive int to a string representation as shown in the Googled example above is extremely helpful.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_numeral_system will be a good starting point.

Comment: Wny recursively? Is this a learning exercise of some sorts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a recursive implementation for converting an int to a binary string, which is what I think this question is asking for:

```
def recursive_bin(i):
    if i == 0:
        return ''
    elif i < 0:
        return '-' + recursive_bin(-i)
    else:
        return recursive_bin(i>>1) + str(i&1)
```

Note that this is only useful as an exercise in recursion, if you are just trying to get at the binary string use the built-in [`bin()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bin) function.

This works because `i&1` will give you the last bit in `i` (either `0` or `1`), and `i>>1` will shift all bits in `i` to the right by one bit (equivalent to division by 2).  Here is an explanation of how this would work for 6 (110<sub>2</sub>):

```
# 6 is 110 in binary
recursive_bin(6)
recursive_bin(6>>1) + str(6 & 1)        -> recursive_bin(3) + '0'
recursive_bin(3>>1) + str(3 & 1) + '0'  -> recursive_bin(1) + '1' + '0'
recursive_bin(1>>1) + str(1 & 1) + '10' -> recursive_bin(0) + '1' + '10'
recursive_bin(0) + '110'                -> '' + '110'
# Final result is '110', since the base case of 0 returns an empty string
```

Comment: You could shorten it a little more with a conditional expression:  `return recursive_bin(i>>1) + str(i&1) if i else ''`

Comment: @mgilson: Losing another line: `recursive_bin = lambda i: recursive_bin(i>>1) + str(i&1) if i else ''`!

Comment: For an exercise in recursion, I was prioritizing readability over short code.  Those are good suggestions, however they will not work for negative numbers.

Answer (score 4):

Python has a builtin function for that:

```
>>> bin(6)
"0b110"
```

And in reverse (kinda):

```
>>> 0b110
6
```

Comment: Or just `'{:b}'.format(6)` (saves slicing off the '0b')

Comment: The reverse would be `int('110', 2)` (kinda)

Comment: Could you explain how to actually convert it in terms of the whole power of 2 thing please? I would also like to understand the mathematical side to it.

Comment: @Jon - that's a true reversal - string back to int. I sort of cheated. I hadn't realized there was a `b` format spec. Does it also exist as `%b`?